# Mockito : mock() calls real method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am new to Mockito, I am using it along with `JUnit4` in Eclipse.
I am trying to mock my method as follows:
`CartLine line = mock(CartLine.class);`
Then I get: `FileNotFoundException` caused by the call of the supposedly mocked method, as shown in the stacktrace below. How is this the expected behaviour? I am using Mockito precisely to avoid using the whole environment.

Stack Trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: cart.properties (file not found)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mycompany.cart.util.ResourceFactory.getFileInputStream(ResourceFactory.java:119)
at com.mycompany.cart.util.ResourceFactory.getProperties(ResourceFactory.java:295)
at com.mycompany.cart.CartSettings.tryLoadSettings(CartSettings.java:215)
at com.mycompany.cart.CartSettings.<init>(CartSettings.java:72)
at com.mycompany.cart.CartSettings.<clinit>(CartSettings.java:60)
at com.mycompany.cart.CartLine.<clinit>(CartLine.java:59)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
at com.redacted.ml.TestConfToJasper.mockCartLine(TestConfToJasper.java:173)
at com.redacted.ml.TestConfToJasper.mockCartLines(TestConfToJasper.java:131)
at com.redacted.ml.TestConfToJasper.testBuildUCSElement(TestConfToJasper.java:75)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
1249 [main] WARN com.redacted.cart.util.ResourceFactory  - Can not find property file:   cart.properties
1249 [main] FATAL com.redacted.cart.CartSettings  - Can not load cart properties!
```

**Edit:** Here is the full test code:

```
private static final CartLine mockCartLine(LineType type) {
    CartLine line = mock(CartLine.class);
    when(line.getLineType()).thenReturn(type);
    return line;
}
```

called by:

```
private static final CartLine[] mockCartLines() {
    CartLine[] lines = new CartLine[10];
    int i=0;

    lines[i++] = mockCartLine(LineType.FO);
            [...]   
    return lines;
}
```

called by:

```
@Test
public void testBuildUCSElement() {
    ConfToJasper ctj = new ConfToJasper(confML);

    CartController controller = mock(CartController.class);
    CartDataObject dataObject = mock(CartDataObject.class);
    CartLine[] lines = mockCartLines();
[...]
}
```

(I am not the creator of this code)

Comment: Please post your test code; the stack trace isn't enough to help.

Comment: Can you post your entire test method?

Comment: Is the `CartLine` class final?  If so, you can't mock it with Mockito.

Comment: You need to post the `CartLine` code, there's some funky things going one there. `CartLine` cannot be final however (Mockito would raised a `MockitoException` saying the class is final)

Comment: I don't have the `CartLine` code, I'm just using it as part of an API...

Answer (score 2):

it seems to me that you have some kind of static initializer in your CartLine which tried to open file stream.

I will strong suggest you cleanup your code to make it unit-test friendly by removing such kind of static initializer logic. (It is usually more appropriate to make it instance method instead)

Or you may have a dummy `cart.properties1 in your testing resources so that your CartLine can read that.

Or you may consider using PowerMock to see if it help to avoid such problem (I doubt anyway...)

Comment: I posted the test code, which I did not write myself. I don't know why the calling methods are `static`, but I tried removing the `static` and got the same result. 
I am unsure of why a static initializer would lead to call the real method instead of the mock. Would you mind to explain?

Comment: I think the problem is not caused by calling the real method.  As I said, it is the ***static*** initializer (clinit in the stack trace) that is throwing the exception.  Take a look in the static initialization logic of your CartLine class

Comment: There is no static initialization of CartLine that I can see. In fact, in my whole test class, apart from the code bits I added in my OP post, the only use of the `static` keyword is for the Mockito and Junit imports, some static final strings and the `@BeforeClass` method.
What I really want to understand though, is: is it a normal behaviour for mockito to end up calling the real method in a `mock()` ? Because no matter if CartLine is staticly or normally initialized, it shouldn't be called. (I added the begginning of the stacktrace that I ellipsed first in my post.)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No it shouldn't be called.  I believe there is static initialization logic that is not obvious in CartLine which caused the problem. from your stack trace, `com.mycompany.cart.CartLine.<clinit>` actually means the class init (which means static initialization) for your CartLine class.  Check about the static variable inside it with type CartSettings, which is the root cause of the problem